# Shutdown timer that turns off computer when playback ends

Tags: shutdown, timer

I wanted to know if there is a shutdown timer that will actually turn off your computer when it detects no more audio signals. Or if itunes/winamp reaches the end of the playlist. The timer must have a sleep function and must be windows capable

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it so I can't attest to its quality, but this seem to be what you are looking for:
http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/21570/itunesshut

Comment: Oh thats to bad, sorry I should have mentioned, for windows

Answer (score 0):

The [ShutItDown](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/shutitdown/43653) plugin for Winamp looks like it should do what you're looking for.